# Is it Possible to Programmatically Limit SFDC Report to More than 99 Rows

Tags: apex, reporting, reports-api

I've been racking my brain on this for a while, and I think its time I ask for some help :)

**Desired Outcome:**

I would like to limit the number of rows in a tabular report to 500. I see that I am able to add a "Row Limit" filter within the Report Builder UI, but the Report Builder restricts me to a row limit of 99 or less.

Is there a programmatic way to use Apex or otherwise to create a report limit of more than 99?

Answer (score 0):

As per Apex developer guide Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API via Apex have some limitations.

Filtering by row limit are unavailable when filtering data.And there are some other limitations.

[Limitations on Reports & Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_limitations.htm)